# Looking for a TIFF Viewer for .NET

Tags: asp.net, tiff

I am looking for a free or commercial programme which will let me open up TIFF files in .NET.

Ideally it would open up in a new window, with 2 restrictions 1) That user isnt able to save the file 2) That there is no print button available.

Does anything come to mind ?

Comment: please refine your question. Based on your comment on Tedds response, you seem to be looking for a combination of TIFF--> generic client rendering or a client/server solution.

Comment: Here is one commercial tiff viewing control for asp.net and winforms, www.tiff-viewer.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any solution which can totally prevent saving/printing.  However there are a few things you can do.

- send a partial image to the browser (i.e. limited to 8bpp, scaled image). For instance, if google maps would use a single TIFF, good luck in saving it a screenshot at a time.
- send degraded image to browser (i.e. use LibTIFF.NET to read (part of) the tiff, convert it to lossy JPG and send that to the browser.
- combination of both
- provide a different css for printer device, which leaves out the image.
- open a new browser window without controls.

You may find some good solutions based on Silverlight or flash, which provide a higher degree of control on the freedom of the user in the browser. If you are searching for those specifically, please update your question accordingly.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick supports a lot of stuff, for instance TIF: http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

It can be used to convert images to other formats.

If I am reading your question correctly (based on the asp.net tag) you actually want a TIFF-viewer for webbrowser? That is unrelated to .Net. To achieve that you'd have to either install a plugin on all the clients or have a JavaScript/Flash/Silverlight app capable of reading and displaying the picture.

Comment: The reason I tagged it as .NET is for the following reason. I basically pull the URL which contains the FULL link to the tiff image from the DB. I think ideally would have a link to the file on my front end, which then opens the TIFF Image in a viewable means. That last part is where I am unsure as I have never worked with Tif images before.